# Are there any open source OS for AP(Access point)?

Tags: operating-system, wifi, embedded-linux

I am not clear with AP(Wireless Access Point) development, I want to know are there any open source OS for it? Or I need to get the os from linux myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Linux-based OS called [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org) that runs on some access points.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Linux distro [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/).  Your wireless card will have to have access point support.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Vyatta](http://www.vyatta.com/).